# Windowsの tree コマンドで、UTF-8 エンコーディングのテキストファイルを出力したい

Tags: windows, コマンドプロンプト

Windowsのコマンドプロンプトで、tree コマンドを試しています。

**質問**
下記でファイル出力すると、SJISになるのですが、UTF-8 形式で出力するにはどうすれば良いですか？

```
tree D:/ /f >D:\out.txt
```

---

**試したこと**
下記設定後、上記コマンド実行しましたが、出力されたファイルのエンコード形式は変わりませんでした。

```
chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001
```

Comment: こんなのがあるようです。[Windows10 April 2018 Updateで追加されたUTF-8モードを使う](https://kuluna.github.io/blog/post/20180512/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShellなら[Out-File](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7)でエンコーディングを指定できます。

```
PS> tree D:/ /f | Out-File -Encoding utf8 D:\out.txt
```

コマンドプロンプトから呼ぶなら

```
C> powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "tree D:/ /f | Out-File -Encoding utf8 D:\out.txt"
```

とかになりますでしょうか。

Comment: 何れの方法でも、期待通り動作しました。